# Use symfony framework with Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, zend-framework

I am begining a project in PHP that needs a framework. I've looked in vain for how to install either Symfony or Zend plugin for Eclipse, my IDE.

Any useful links or indications, please ?

Comment: Why do you think you need a plugin for this?

Comment: @TimFountain Maybe, the expression of a beginner. I want to use a framework and I want to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

- Either for Zend or Symfony, to use it in eclipse PDT, you need first to download it from the official web site ([zend's latest download page](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest), [Symfony's download page](http://symfony.com/download)). Then, add the library to eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> PHP Libraries and then new, navigate to the downloaded directory). Finally, after creating the project, right-click on it, Include Path -> Configure Include Path -> Add Library -> Choose User Library then next and select the needed libraries.
- For Yii framework, you need to install the [Yiiclipse plugin](http://yiiclipse.maziarz.org/updatesite/STABLE/) for your eclipse PDT.

I hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.dubture.com/installation/

But the best support Symfony in PhpStorm, look at the gifs: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm

Comment: @TimFountain I post link to symfony plugin for PDT: http://symfony.dubture.com/installation/

Answer (score 0):

I also use PHP Storm at work but I'm just too cheap to buy it for home, so I use Eclipse with the Symfony plug-in!  You can download it from the Eclipse marketplace for free, though it is only for Symfony 2.0, Symfony 2.5 is recognized, there are just a few features missing.  I found that it still can be useful for code hinting and many Symfony-related helpers still pop up.  It beats no helpers or hinting but it does lack many intuitive and time-saving features found in PHP Storm.

Anyway, here's the link directly from the Eclipse plug-in page:  http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/symfony-plugin

If you have Eclipse open, you can even just drag and drop the "Install" icon directly onto Eclipse and it should install automatically.  Best of luck to you, @sk001!